# All-key entities (and their simplification)

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, composite-primary-key

Is there a way (with Doctrine 2) to have entities embedded into each other (without the nead of even having a table for certain entities)? The easiest example to have a class like:

```
class Point {

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $x;

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $y;
}
```

Then embedding this into an other object like:

```
class Line {

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Point")
     * @JoinColumn(name="start_x", referencedColumnName="x")
     * @JoinColumn(name="start_y", referencedColumnName="y")
     **/
    private $start;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     **/
    private $length;
}
```

The point: all fields of `Point` comprise to it's primary key and it is in fact embedded into `Line` so there is no point of having a table with it.

I know about one possibility to use `array` as type and let PHP serialize the point into a varchar field, but that would eliminate the very point I'm using an ORM instead of a *key-value, everything serialized* storage scheme.